# phpMyAdmin error #2002 xampp on windows 7

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Yesterday was working pretty fine, today I'm facing that error. MySql es up and running, apache is up too. Disabled firewall, tested with and without password in root user; no way, phpmyadmin stills failing.

Also facing this message:"The MySQL server is not running or is blocked by a firewall! Please check this problem first ..." inside security check section..

This is error log:

```
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-07-05 12:14:21 1634 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1626184 and 1626184 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1626304 in the ib_logfiles!
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2014-07-05 12:14:21 5780 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2014-07-05 12:14:22 5780 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-07-05 12:14:22 5780 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-07-05 12:14:22 5780 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.16 started; log sequence number 1626304
2014-07-05 12:14:22 5780 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 6565
2014-07-05 12:14:22 5780 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-07-05 12:14:22 5780 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-07-05 12:14:22 5780 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-07-05 12:14:22 5780 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-07-05 12:14:22 5780 [Note] e:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.16'  socket: ''  port: 6565  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was my fault:

I have two mysql process instances (one for workbench and the other for xampp)